# apache poi: images in spreadsheet are associated with workbook and can not be retrieved/linked with individual worksheet ..

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read images from xl_sheet using method  wbook.getAllpicture(); but I found that these images are returning as whole I can not keep images separated according workshets.

Answer (score 1):

In `Excel` the pictures data are stored on `Workbook` level. This is what [Workbook.getAllPictures](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#getAllPictures--) actually gets.

Each sheet has a `Drawing` layer which hovers over the sheet. In this `Drawing` are `Shapes` which are anchored to the sheet and may also be linked to the pictures data stored on `Workbook` level. If so, the shape does showing that picture.

So for getting the pictures dependent of the sheets, we must run over the appropriate `Drawing` layer, determining whether the shape we found is linked to a picture. If so, we get that picture.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ExcelGetXSSFPicturesWithPosition {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelWithImages.xlsx"));
  //Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelWithImages.xls"));

  for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
   String sheetname = sheet.getSheetName();

   Drawing drawing = sheet.getDrawingPatriarch();

   if (drawing instanceof XSSFDrawing) {
    for (XSSFShape shape : ((XSSFDrawing)drawing).getShapes()) {
     if (shape instanceof XSSFPicture) {
      XSSFPicture xssfPicture = (XSSFPicture)shape;
      String shapename = xssfPicture.getShapeName();
      int row = xssfPicture.getClientAnchor().getRow1();
      int col = xssfPicture.getClientAnchor().getCol1();
System.out.println(
 "Picture with Shapename: " + shapename + 
 " is located sheet: " + sheetname + 
 ", row: " + row + 
 ", col: " + col
 );

     }
    }
   } else if (drawing instanceof HSSFPatriarch) {
    for (HSSFShape shape : ((HSSFPatriarch)drawing).getChildren()) {
     if (shape instanceof HSSFPicture) {
      HSSFPicture hssfPicture = (HSSFPicture)shape;
      String shapename = hssfPicture.getShapeName();
      int row = hssfPicture.getClientAnchor().getRow1();
      int col = hssfPicture.getClientAnchor().getCol1();
System.out.println(
 "Picture with Shapename: " + shapename + 
 " is located sheet: " + sheetname + 
 ", row: " + row + 
 ", col: " + col
 );

     }
    }
   }
  }

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

For getting the picture data out of the `XSSFPicture` we can use [XSSFPicture.getPictureData](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFPicture.html#getPictureData--). And for the `HSSFPicture` we can use [HSSFPicture.getPictureData](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFPicture.html#getPictureData--).

That both provides [PictureData.getData](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/PictureData.html#getData--) which returns a `byte[]` containing the binary data of the picture.